# Can't Automatically Select JOption Pane showInputDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

So I have a `JOptionPane` like this in the very beginning of my main method:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Input");
String progName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Name?");
```

However, before I can start typing, I need to manually go click on the pop up. Is there any way to make it so that as soon as I run the program, it will automatically "select" the pop up so that when I start typing it will just be in the text box. If this can't be done with a `JOptionPane`, I am OK with other alternatives, I just need to get a user inputted string with the above constraint in mind.

Comment: You are not supposed to run any Swing code in your `main` method.  Doing so leads to unpredictable behavior.  Nearly all Swing methods and constructors need to run in the AWT Event Dispatch thread.  See [the javax.swing package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/package-summary.html) and the [Concurrency in Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: I just wrote your code and it does exactly what you need (place the focus on the text field and you can start writing right away).

Comment: See [Dialog Focus](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) which presents a solution for modal components such as (some) dialogs and all option panes.

Comment: *"However, before I can start typing, I need to manually go click on the pop up."* Why? Here, the text field of the option pane has focus the instant it appears. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I'm not really sure what causes me to have to click on the pop up. Running the code on other computers seems to give focus to the option pane instantly, so it may just be that I've done something weird to my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a simple example in which the logic for asking the user's name is concentrated in a single method. This method is called at the very start of the application and every time you click on a button.

This way, the user is forced to enter the data when the application starts and every time he/she wishes to change the entered value.

```
public class Jf53136132 extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3336501835025139522L;

    private JPanel contentPane;



    public Jf53136132() {
        setTitle("Jf53136132");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btnInvokeJoptionpane = new JButton("set some text on label");
        panel.add(btnInvokeJoptionpane);

        JLabel lblx = new JLabel("-x-");
        panel.add(lblx);

        getNewTextForLabel(lblx);

        btnInvokeJoptionpane.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                getNewTextForLabel(lblx);
            }
        });
    }



    private void getNewTextForLabel(JLabel label) {
        String inputText = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the text for the label");
        System.out.println("you entered <" + inputText + ">");
        if (inputText != null && !inputText.trim().isEmpty()) {
            label.setText(inputText);
        }
    }

}
```

Notice how the method getNewTextForLabel(...) is called as soon as the label is added to the content pane and at every click of the button.

Also, as VGR correctly pointed out, it is a good practice to not run any Swing code inside the main application thread.
You can have a look at the java tutorials for swing ([here's a classic example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html)).

The following is some example code that runs the frame on a separate thread.

```
public class Main {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        Jf53136132 f = new Jf53136132();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }



    void execute() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().execute();
    }

}
```